# Preventing relayout due to scrollbar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, scrollbar

How can I prevent the body of the page being "pushed" to the left when a scrollbar appears due to ajax content?
I can of course set overflow:scroll to the body, but it wouldn't look nice.

I am using bootstrap, but I guess it is a general question.

Comment: body content being pushed ?? Not clear. Be more specific. I don't think there is such a thing called being pushed away. Might be because  of your markup or styles. Put up something to debug. Fiddle please

Comment: The page originally doesn't have the scrollbar. Then ajax appends more content and the scrollbar appears. To account for the width of the scrollbar the original body is "pushed". I see this happens in chrome and Firefox. I'll put a fiddle later if there is no other answer.

Comment: I mean the scroll bar is of size say 10px. That won't affect you drastically. Negligible shift ryt. You cannot handle this issue without specifying overflow: scroll. Else you have to go for a custom scrollbar with z-index.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How Do I Stop My Web Content From Shifting Left When The Vertical Scrollbar Appears? Roll-Up of Advice 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45524214/how-do-i-stop-my-web-content-from-shifting-left-when-the-vertical-scrollbar-appe)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can create a container that have a fixed width, and give the content the same width (same static width - not `100%`).
that way, when the content overflows the parent, the scroll will not push the content but will flow above it.

using that, you can apply a cool way to scroll without pushing anything. by showing the scroll only when you hover the container.

Check out this simple [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/avrahamcool/NKJRZ/)

EDIT: 
[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/avrahamcool/NKJRZ/2/) I show the difference between setting static width, and %.

Comment: @user2643506 If it's working for you, you should accept it as a correct answer.

Answer (score 25):

#### `overflow: overlay`

Building on [avrahamcool's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19209997/3217306), you can use the property `overflow: overlay`.

> Behaves the same as `auto`, but with the scrollbars drawn on top of content instead of taking up space. Only supported in WebKit-based (e.g., Safari) and Blink-based (e.g., Chrome or Opera) browsers.

Source: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow#Values)

This is great for when you need horizontally-scrolling content and don't want it to change size when scrollbars appear on hover.

**Caveat:** it is deprecated. Support is pretty much limited to Chromium, but that might go away in the future. See https://caniuse.com/css-overflow-overlay.

However, you can do a fallback of `auto`:

```css
.container:hover {
    overflow: auto; /* fallback */
    overflow: overlay;
}
```

Demo: [jsfiddle.net/NKJRZ/385/](http://jsfiddle.net/NKJRZ/385/)

---

Can I Use also has an interesting note:

> This value is deprecated and related functionality being standardized as [the `scrollbar-gutter` property](https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_properties_scrollbar-gutter).

However, you should check their link because browser support for this experimental feature is no better than `overflow: overlay` as of November 2021.

Comment: Unfortunately it is deprecated.

Answer (score 8):

Well, the scrollbar will always push your content aside, there is really nothing you can do about that. What you can do is to always show to scrollbar for example:

```
html,body {
    height:101%;
}
```

or

```
html {
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

The best way to do this is assign value 'overlay' to overflow property. This works fine.

```
    overflow-y: overlay;
```

Comment: Unfortunately it is deprecated and no longer supported.

Answer (score 2):

In 2023 there is a `scrollbar-gutter` property. `scrollbar-gutter: stable;` does the trick. Supported by every browser apart from Opera.

Comment: As of 12/23 scrollbar-gutter doesnt have any support on Safari or Safari on iOS

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was getting an annoying pop event on my navbar whenever the scrollbar appears, but applying position fixed on my nav solved it for me.